# FCKeditor vs TinyMCE and XHTML Compliance

Tags: html, tinymce, fckeditor, richtextediting

I'm after (short) opinions on FCKeditor vs TinyMCE and whether either or both are XHTML compliant.

In the interest of keeping with the spirit of stackoverflow, if someone has already made your point, just upvote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience FCKEditor does indeed produce XHTML compliant code, but that code is slightly different depending on what browser you're in.  Mostly, this was related to the enter key producing either a break or a paragraph, and I think it may have been configurable.

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE produces absolute garbage. FCK produces less garbage, but can also conflict with browser-in-built styling (by default FCK styles with tags rather than style attributes, eg <strong> rather than <span style="font-weight: bold;">, however hitting cmd-b in Safari produces the latter, and FCK will be unaware of it, thus allowing you to nest styles to no effect, and not allowing you to use FCK functionality to reverse in-built functionality).

Both produce garbage in IE but that is because IE's DOM is insane.

For instance: http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/07/contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, they both allow the browser to mess with the code they produce, which doesn't result in XHTML compliance.

[XStandard](http://xstandard.com/) is the only rich web editor I'm aware of that produces XHTML compliant code, but unfortunately it requires a client-side install, which rules it out for real web stuff.